# How to store all the outputs of loop in form of dictionary of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I have created a for loop and what I want is that the end result of each iteration of the loop to be stored as a dictionary(tfdict). Now what I need is all the dicts to be combined in one dict get that final dict.

```
for i in range(0,len(sep)):
    n=len(sep[i])
    tfDict = dict.fromkeys(setwords,0)
    for word in sep[i]:
            tfDict[word]+=1
            tfDict[word] = tfDict[word]/n
    x=fin.values()
    for word,val in tfDict.items():
        for w,v in fin.items():
            x = v
            if(word==w):
                tfDict[word]=val*x
    print(tfDict)
```

here on print this inside the loop, I get the needed output

```
{'and': 0.0, 'document': 0.23783346831109634, 'first': 0.0, 'is': 0.16666666666666666, 'one': 0, 'second': 0.16666666666666666, 'the': 0.16666666666666666, 'third': 0, 'this': 0.16666666666666666}
{'and': 0.3193817886456925, 'document': 0.0, 'first': 0.0, 'is': 0.16666666666666666, 'one': 0.16666666666666666, 'second': 0, 'the': 0.16666666666666666, 'third': 0.16666666666666666, 'this': 0.16666666666666666}
{'and': 0.0, 'document': 0.24462871026284194, 'first': 0.3021651247531982, 'is': 0.2, 'one': 0, 'second': 0, 'the': 0.2, 'third': 0, 'this': 0.2}
```

Now, I want all of this outside the loop as well, in from of dict of dict or panda. Is there a way i can do this?

Comment: They can't all be a single dict, they have the same keys.  You can have a `list` which could contain all of these dictionaries however, and you could turn that into a pandas dataframe

Comment: try ```defaultdict(list)```